# Can pressure create the same effect as gravity?

Tags: gravity

So here's my question: In high gravity environments we'd literally be crushed and extreme water pressure produces the same result. So is it at all possible that we could provide a pressurized environment that creates something similar to Earth's gravity?

Comment: what do you think would happen in a contained high pressure environment in space?

Comment: Gravity operates in one direction only.  Fluid pressure acts in every direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No and here's the difference.

In extremely high gravity, we would be flattened against the ground. Our bones could not support our own weight and would break.

In a high pressure environment, we would implode; crushed from all sides. Our bones would be perfectly capable of supporting us and (if there were no gravity to begin with) we could even fly around the room, but the high pressure would act on us like your fist around a Styrofoam ball (there are also numerous other effects that high pressure gases have on your blood vessels, brain, lungs, ears, etc)

What to take home from this? There are many ways to be crushed, but not all of them are the same thing.

Comment: Re, "In a high pressure environment, we would implode; crushed from all sides."  Not true.  Everything that you are made of is practically incompressible.  The thing that would kill you at very high pressures, assuming that the gas mix you were given to breathe was not toxic at that pressure, would be changes in metabolic processes and other chemical processes that are essential to the functioning of your cells.

Comment: @jameslarge I'm not saying you're wrong, but I have to tailor my answer to the level of the OP. You might be reading into the word "implode" too much. That word was my attempt to illustrate the different types of "crushed" that the OP refers to. Not only that, but high pressure certainly would cause damaging reorganizing of systems, can burst eardrums, etc.

Comment: (Now I'm getting off track again) My point was that, yeah the worst thing is the effect on metabolic processes *if* you're already pressure acclimatized, but to emphasize merely that the two types of "crushed" are separate (which is what led to the OP's confusion), I went with "implode". However, I would be happy to change it if you can think of a more accurate variant of "crushed" that would fit with a plausible case involving high pressure

Comment: High pressure, by itself, will do no harm to your eardrums. What hurts your ears is if the pressure in your inner ear is different from the external pressure. That can happen if the external pressure _changes_ faster than you can equalize your inner ear pressure.

Comment: "Crushed" and "imploded" both connote drastic, and life-threatening changes in gross physical structure.  If you tell me that somebody was crushed, then I'm going to picture broken bones, hemorrhaging, etc.  Not subtle changes in protein chemistry.

Comment: @jameslarge Treating your body as incompressible is a decent approximation for scuba divers but fails at really high pressure. The compressibility of water is not zero, after all, and we are mostly made of water. At high enough pressures, you would definitely implode.

Comment: @MarkMitchison, implode into what? The answer above talks about a "fist around a styrofoam ball."  You can crush styrofoam into its self because it's foam---mostly empty space.  Human tissue doesn't have any empty space unless the "really high pressure" you're talking about is enough to "implode" it into degenerate matter.  (e.g., the way the solid plutonium core of a nuclear weapon is "imploded" by the high-explosive "lens" that initiates a nuclear explosion.)  That's not quite what I had pictured when I read the phrase, "pressurized environment" in the original question.

Comment: @jameslarge would silly putty have been a more acceptable simile?

Answer (score 0):

As james large pointed out in his comment, fluid pressure acts on all sides of a body, and only acts (directly) on the external portions of the body.

As far as simulating gravity goes, it MAY be able to hold you against the ground if you pressed yourself flat to the ground and created a vacuum seal around your body, but if any gap were left for gas to pass under you, the pressure below you would equalize with that above you, and you would be “weightless”.

So no, fluid pressure can *theoretically* hold an object against a surface if there is no flow between them, but it could not cause any objects to accelerate in a certain direction.